# preview selected image on popup in angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload, ng-dialog, ng-img-crop

I am using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) / [ngImgCrop](https://github.com/alexk111/ngImgCrop) and [ngDialog](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngDialog) to make a dynamic app using angularjs 1.5 version.

I have an input field which trigger by another element. I want to open the pop-up and give the ability to crop the image using above libraries. It's working without the pop-up but when I use the popup , the image not preview.

If I add an input field inside the popup to select , it's working. Seems like it fails if I select the image before open the popup.How to solve this?

```
I tried http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/xxo3sk41/590/ way and open the popup with input change event but no success.
```

Comment: create a jsfiddle or post your code